# How to remove language from the URL and use the default one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use Nextjs (App Router) and I made it multilangual following [the doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization) explanations.

Now the routes look like this:

```
https://example.com/en/article
https://example.com/fa/article
```

So I want to remove the lang (`en`) which is the default language, so, here is the expected routes:

```
https://example.com/article
https://example.com/fa/article
```

Any idea how can I do that?

---

Here is the code I have:

/src/app/[lang]/page.js

```
// 'use client'
import { getDictionary } from './dictionaries'
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";

// const router = useRouter();
export default async function Page({ params: { lang } }) {
    const dict = await getDictionary(lang) // en
    return (
        <>
            <button>{dict.products.cart}</button>
       </>
    ) // Add to Cart
}`
```

/src/app/[lang]/dictionaries.js

```
import 'server-only'

const dictionaries = {
    en: () => import('../dictionaries/en.json').then((module) => module.default),
    fa: () => import('../dictionaries/fa.json').then((module) => module.default),
}

export const getDictionary = async (locale) => dictionaries[locale]()
```

And I have `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fa'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

Comment: By doing this I suspect you'll end up having more routing problems to solve down the line. Is there a particular reason why having `en` in the URL is a problem, and why you think you need to remove it?

Comment: @Andy Since my website wasn't multilingual in the past, so I've over 1M links indexed in google. That's why I need to keep links as they were.